# WEB-INF/lib not showing in weblogic classpath

Tags: java, weblogic, classpath

I have a spring mvc application deployed on a weblogic server .. However the problem is , none of the libraries in my WEB-INF/lib shows up in classpath .. Is there any entry I need to do somewhere for these libraries to be included in my classpath ..

Comment: What exactly does 'shows up in classpath' mean, a classpath defined some in WebLogic or are you talking about the classpath environment variable?

Comment: thanks a ton for the reply .. what I meant is the libraries are not added to the weblogic classpath .. e.g in one of the pages I get -> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
 .. Though the required library for this class is present in the WEB-INF/lib directory  ..